# Add xml metatag on python 2.54

Tags: python, xml, meta-tags

I am writing a python 2.54 script that uses the object xml.etree.ElementTree. I'm using the function write in order to write the resulted xml into a file. Thing is, I need to have an XML meta tag: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, and as noted in here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write

All that needs to be done is passing true on the second parameter of write. But that seemed to work only on python 2.6 and up.

Any ideas how can this be done on python 2.5.4 (If this is possible, that is...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems the easiest way to force writing a xml declaration is to pass a different encoding then `us-ascii` or `utf-8`. This is not really documented, but a quick look at the [source for the `write()` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/de34c7b097e8/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l655) reveals this:

```
def write(self, file, encoding="us-ascii"):
    assert self._root is not None
    if not hasattr(file, "write"):
        file = open(file, "wb")
    if not encoding:
        encoding = "us-ascii"
    elif encoding != "utf-8" and encoding != "us-ascii":
        file.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='%s'?>\n" % encoding)
    self._write(file, self._root, encoding, {})
```

The comparison is case sensitive, so if you use `encoding="UTF-8"` (not `encoding="utf-8"`), you'll end up exactly with what you want.